# How does returning a text from controller without a view show it in browser?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, web

This might be a very silly question but I'm just curious and I'm sure I'll end up knowing more about what's going on.

In a typical .NET MVC website, if you create a controller without any view and return a string from the Index() function, the string will show up in browser.

So, without a view, how does this happen ?

My understanding is that server returns a string and the browser just shows it. As simple as that. So that means browser creates the HTML to include the text?
I feel I'm missing some core concepts of web here.

Would appreciate some details.

Comment: A view is nothing more than a blueprint which will generate HTML and the data you pass to the view will be integrated in it. Afterwards, the HTML is returned to the client. It's important to realize that HTML is really just plain text with a few special keywords in it, which is then parsed by the browser. The browser can also display plain text *without* those keywords, it will just look very ugly. Returning a simple string from a controller is an example of this.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers can read text, html, jpeg, xml, json, pdf and a lot of other formats. They aren't html exclusive.

When you return a string, what MVC is actually doing is writing that response directly to the return buffer (aka the response body) and setting the content-type to plain/text (i think?).

and the browser just display what the server served.